# Java GAE comunication with external server, fastest way

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine

I have a backend in Java on GAE and trying to communicate with it from external server(using php). It just one way communiaton, php just sends a request and gets string as answer.

Currently I'm using curl(php side) and java just outputing the data normaly as it were a website(so in fact php just fetching data from url - that's how it's called?:D).

I doubt it's the fastest way?

Cheers

**EDIT**:
Ok, so it seems HTTP is the only way? To speed up the loading time of php page i could just use cache. The data on the GAE backend updates every 45 minutes and it's not crucial to get the new data just at the time it appears, so recaching stored data on php server every 45/50 minutes should be fine? So there want me so many requests to backend?

It seems like kind of good solutions, but maybe someone knows better ones?

Comment: I don't see any other way. GAE applications are only accessible through HTTP, AFAIK.

Comment: what kind of performance have you seen so far, and what kind of performance are you expecting?  why do you doubt it is the fastest way?  what kind of data are you sending?  are you expecting lots of requests with small sizes, or a few requests with large sizes?  what kind of data are you sending?    When you say "fastest" do you mean low latency or high throughput?  where is your current bottleneck?  serializing the data or sending it over the network?  As it stands, your question is much too vague to answer :)

Comment: I just send short strings, like 200 chars

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to format your communications between your services, but all of them will rely on HTTP, and as a result none of them will be significantly faster or slower. Pick whichever format provides you with the most flexibility and easiest itegration.